# Creating a 'Table' From Two Data-Sets

Tags: r, matrix

I have two 4x1 matrices with which I would like to multiply each term in one with all 4 terms in the other. The best way I can describe it is I wish to write R code that will yield the 4x4 matrix shown in the photo attached.

```
rm(list = ls())
cat("\014")  
graphics.off()

x<- c(1,2,3,4)
y<- c(5,2,1,2)
```

The problem I am having is that I am only getting back a 4x1 matrix, as opposed to the desired 4x4 shown below

Desired Result

[image: Desired Result]

Comment: you can also try `outer(y, x)`

Answer (score 1):

Note that your expected result is just the result of a matrix multiplication:

```
> matrix(y) %*% x

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    5   10   15   20
[2,]    2    4    6    8
[3,]    1    2    3    4
[4,]    2    4    6    8
```

Answer (score 1):

You have many ways to make it, e.g.,

```
> outer(y, x)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    5   10   15   20
[2,]    2    4    6    8
[3,]    1    2    3    4
[4,]    2    4    6    8

> kronecker(y, t(x))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    5   10   15   20
[2,]    2    4    6    8
[3,]    1    2    3    4
[4,]    2    4    6    8

> y %x% t(x)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    5   10   15   20
[2,]    2    4    6    8
[3,]    1    2    3    4
[4,]    2    4    6    8
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the `sapply`

```r
sapply(x, `*`, y)


     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    5   10   15   20
[2,]    2    4    6    8
[3,]    1    2    3    4
[4,]    2    4    6    8
```

also with `purrr::map`

```r
len <- length(x)
map(x, ~ .x*y) %>% as.data.frame() %>% setNames(1:len)

  1  2  3  4
1 5 10 15 20
2 2  4  6  8
3 1  2  3  4
4 2  4  6  8
```

Comment: The names that you forced in the solution matrix *don't match* the names in the OP. I think the OP wanted as names the values of each vector, so that you can see the result of multiplying one name times the other (i.e: 5 x 1 = 5 in the first row, first column of your solution)

Comment: but the issue i see here is that we cannot have the duplicates as rownames